# What's wrong with this excel formula nest?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So in an excel document, I have the following formula...

> =IFERROR(=IF(E2 = "Graphic", $H$2, 0), H3)

What I want to do is an If/Else statement, but Excel doesn't have that formula.

I want to say, If E2 = Grahic, print data from cell H2 in active cell. If not, print data from cell H3

Can anyone help me with a suggested formula?

Comment: `=` should not precede all functions, just the beginning: `=IFERROR(IF(E2 = "Graphic", $H$2, 0), H3)`

Comment: `IF` is a if/else statement in Excel. If you're talking about deeper nesting you'd use nested `IF` statements.

Comment: Seth. Yes, sorry. If/Else wasn't the exact command I meant, but the nested IF's might work.  @Máté Juhász: Thanks heaps, I'll give it a shot

Comment: I think all you need is `=IF(E2="Graphic",$H$2,H3)`.  As @Seth said, Excel's `IF()` functions as an `IF/ELSE` statement.  This formula says:  If `E2="Graphic"`, return `$H$2`, otherwise return `H3`.

Comment: Since you are using IFERROR then the Formula should be written like =IFERROR(IF(E2 = "Graphic", $H$2, 0), H3) other wise it should work even if is like =IF(E2="Graphic",$H$2,H3). Your mistake was =IFERROR(=if(,,, only one '=' sign is allowed.

Comment: @Bandersnatch... That formula works, and thats what I ended up doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer Below:

```
=IF( E2 = "Graphic", $H$2, $H$3 )
```

**IF** function is broken down into 3 parts:

```
= IF ( Logic , If Logic is TRUE, If Logic is FALSE )
```

You can wrap the whole thing within `IFERROR`, this will say if the function returns an *Error*, then do something else:

```
= IFERROR(  IF( E2 = "Graphic", $H$2, $H$3 ) , "Something Else")
```